# SVG Foreign Object not displaying with SVG Namespace

Tags: svg

I have the following SVG file.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

<!--<svg width="100%" height="500">-->
<svg id="deviceImage" class="DeviceImage" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin" currentScale="1" width="3000px" height="1500px" oncontextmenu="return false">

  <script type="text/ecmascript">
    <![CDATA[
    
    function ExmpleFunction(event, componentGroup)
    {
       alert('Hello World');
    }  
    
    ]]>
  </script>
  
  <defs>
    <!-->>>TestShape>>>-->
    <symbol id="TestShape">
      <polygon points="1,1 650,1 630,175 21,175"></polygon>
    </symbol>
    <!--<<<TestShape<<<-->
  </defs>

  <!--TestShape-->
  <g id="p1" transform="translate(50, 35)" visibility="visible">
    <use  id="p2Basic" xlink:href = "#TestShape"/>
  </g>

  <rect x="500" y="10" width="100" height="150" fill="blue"/>

  <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="200" height="250">
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <embed id="wert" src="TestModule-Basic.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />
    </div>
  </foreignObject>

</svg>
```

The aim is to embed another svg image which supports the internal script (so this can't be done as an image) so I am using foreignObject

When run the above code displays the test shape and the rectangle, but it does not display the svg image in the foreignObject.

By experimenting I discovered that if I remove the xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" from the main SVG node, the svg image in the foreignObject is displayed but the test shape and rectangle are not displayed. I also see the text within the script tag as part of the image.

I obviously need to include the svg namespace but I am not sure how I get both to display?

All help appreciated!

Comment: Which browser ? works fine for me in latest FF, Chrome and Safari on osX when accessed directly. How are you displaying this svg doc?

Comment: I am using IE11 and you're right it works fine in Chrome! Any ideas how I can get it to work in IE as I have to use it?  I can't believe I have fallen for that again and wasted so much time.

Comment: I won't be the one who will help you for IE here, sorry. I even thought IE <Edge didn't support the `<foreignObject>` tag. A workaround would be to fetch the external doc through xhr and append it in your svg as an `<svg>` element.

Comment: That was going to be my fallback plan I don't suppose you have an example? Thaks for your help!